# Add effect when a div has been removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, effect

I want add effect to this "move up" of other `div` when I `remove` one.
Here html:

```
<ul id="fds">
  <li>
    <h3>one</h3>
    <p>Hello guys</p>
    <p>
      <button class="remove">x</button>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>two</h3>
    <p>Hello guys</p>
    <p>
      <button class="remove">x</button>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>three</h3>
    <p>Hello guys</p>
    <p>
      <button class="remove">x</button>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>four</h3>
    <p>Hello guys</p>
    <p>
      <button class="remove">x</button>
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here JavaScript:

```
$("#fds").delegate(".remove", 'click', function() {
    var $li = $(this).closest("li");
  $li.fadeOut(300, function() {
    $li.remove();
  })
})
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/stefalber/L0prkrct/13/) a JS to test this.

Comment: @Andreas "I want add effect to this "move up" of other div when I remove one.".

Comment: Please mark the correct answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the top margin to minus the height to give a better UX.

```js
$("#fds").delegate(".remove", 'click', function() {
    var $li = $(this).closest("li");
    
  $li.css({opacity: 0}).animate({marginTop: -1 * $li.height()}, 400, function() {$li.remove();})
})
```

```css
li
{
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="fds">
  <li>
    <h3>one</h3>
    <p>Hello guys</p>
    <p>
      <button class="remove">x</button>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>two</h3>
    <p>Hello guys</p>
    <p>
      <button class="remove">x</button>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>three</h3>
    <p>Hello guys</p>
    <p>
      <button class="remove">x</button>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>four</h3>
    <p>Hello guys</p>
    <p>
      <button class="remove">x</button>
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this way the element will be actually hidden after animation is done.

```
$li.animate({ 
   height: 0, 
   opacity: 0,
}, 'slow', function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L0prkrct/19/

Comment: Removing `padding: 0` the movement is less fluid.

Comment: You are right. Maybe Martijn will revert the answer to original one. Until then   jsfiddle example is using complete code.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/L0prkrct/16/) is close to what you want.

Just add `$li.animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, 'slow');` before the fadeOut.

Here your JSfiddle updated. https://jsfiddle.net/L0prkrct/16/